# MotionEnded Not working on device

Tags: ios, objective-c

FIXED

Have removed the animation and this has resolved the issue.

EDIT
I have added more data to the plist file and iv noticed its just going throught he whole database not just showing one question. How would i go about fixing this?

I have the following code that fires on the end of a shake. However on simulator its working fine but on the device itsself its not. Its basicly fireing alot of calls and i can hear the sound playing mutiple times.

Is there a way to stop this and make sure it only fires ones on shake?

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
// Do your thing after shaking device

if ([plistArray count] == 0) {
    self.text.text = @"Please Upgrade for more";
    [Animations fadeIn:self.text andAnimationDuration:1.0 andWait:YES];

}
else    {

    AVAudioPlayer *showsound;
    NSString *audiopath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mouse1" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *audiourl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audiopath];
    showsound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:audiourl error:Nil];
    [showsound play];

    ////display random quote from array
    int randV = arc4random() % self.plistArray.count;


    self.text.text = self.plistArray[randV];
    [self.plistArray removeObjectAtIndex:randV];
    //fade text in
    [Animations fadeIn:self.text andAnimationDuration:1.0 andWait:YES];

    //play sound



}
```

}

Comment: It doesn't look like you're filtering all motion types except the shake.

Comment: i have used the bellow code if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
    {
        // your code
    }

Comment: However this dosent just show one result shows all

Comment: How are you actually shaking the device? Do you shake it continually for 10+ seconds or more? Or do you just do it once, quickly?

Comment: It should just be a quick shake, back and forth. Nothing more is needed to trigger the shake. Add an `NSLog()` and see exactly how many motions are being detected. Try running just the code in my suggestion. I updated to include an `NSLog()`.

Comment: ist only being fired once in nslog so must be my if statment

Comment: However when i copy my if statment in it then fires lots of times?

Comment: worked it out its all todo with the animation code removed that and working fine. It must be the animation duration is to slow meaning the next shake is exicuted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-motionEnded` is being called multiple times for other motions you might be making with the device. If you only want to isolate the shake do so like this:

```
#pragma mark - UIResponder motion event methods

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if ( motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake ) {
        // do something only for shakes
        NSLog(@"shaken ... ");
    }
 }
```

Comment: I tried this and still going through all the data in the plist file?